# Rank vs Independent Variables - Multiple Regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

This is very much a 'for fun' project I'm working on, but my stats knowledge is very limited (number theorist and algebra-focused mathematician usually!), so I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible / straightforward to do. And even then, I'm not sure how I could potentially analyse the data.

Some preamble: I like visiting theme parks and riding roller coasters, and one of the things I like to do is keep a rank of my favourites. When speaking with a friend, he asked if there was any way I could "predict" how much I'd like a roller coaster based solely on its statistics (height, length, maximum speed, number of times it goes upside).

I currently have 115 entries. Under a random tutorial I looked at, I tried the following using RStudio:

```
install.packages('psych') 
library('psych')
pairs.panels(RankForR, lm=TRUE)
summary(lm(Rank ~ Length+Height+Speed+Inversions, data=Rankings))
```

This gives a matrix of entries:
[image: Matrix]
where I believe the top left numbers are a Pearson coefficient for correlation. But this is only piecewise? And equally, this only shows correlation between the data I have, as opposed to giving me an equation for working out Rank.

So, the question ares:

1. Is there any way to see how well the variables together correlate to Rank?
2. Is there any way to find some sort of closed formula for working out Rank using the other 4 pieces of data?

NB: I'm fully prepared for the answers to be 'no' / 'this isn't something you can do' / 'the correlation is so weak it's pointless'. But just something I've been curious over..

---

If it's helpful for a working example, I've including 10 entries of the data table I'm working with...

```
  Rank Length  Height  Speed Inversions
     1   4331    98.4   72.7        0
     2   3622   170.6   65.9        4
     3   3560   119.8   57.2        5
     4   4531   134.5   62.1        7
     5   3511   118.1   55.9        0
     6   2349    42.7   50.0        4
     7   2231   105.0   54.1        2
     8   2585    72.4   46.6        0
     9   3534   104.5   54.0        0
    10   3983   159.7   65.9        0
```

Comment: I would be good if you posted the results from your ```summary``` call in your question! In principle, this will reflect the joint explanatory value of all your independent variables in modelling your dependent variable. In that last line you are effectively doing [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares). You model Rank as a linear function of all independent variables in an additive manner. Note also that it might make sense to add a constant to your model.

Comment: The result from this call: `lm(Rank ~ Length+Height+Speed+Inversions, data=Rankings)` is the your model for prediction.  Using a data frame of variables the `predict()` function will calculate the predicted ranking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments below your post, you just have to print the `summary` of your `lm` call to get the answer to your first question.

I called the same `lm` function with your sample data:

```
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 20.1493500  7.2273170   2.788   0.0385 *
Length       0.0003826  0.0019389   0.197   0.8513  
Height       0.0312308  0.0322633   0.968   0.3775  
Speed       -0.3119693  0.1973701  -1.581   0.1748  
Inversions  -0.5651964  0.3549401  -1.592   0.1722  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 2.72 on 5 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5515,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1926 
F-statistic: 1.537 on 4 and 5 DF,  p-value: 0.3205
```

Looking at the bottom of the table, the [R-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) value tells you how much of the variance of $Rank$ is explained by the combination of all roller coaster characteristics. However, adding variables in a model will always increase the $R^2$, even if it is just by a tiny portion - which will be the case if you add to your model a roller coaster characteristic  unrelated to your dependent $Rank$ variable. We therefore have to adjust the $R^2$ value for the number of variables in our model - which is what the adjusted $R^2$ does. It is much lower (0.19), showing that all of these variables, when considered together, actually don't explain the variance of $Rank$ that much.

Next, we want to look at the F- and p-statistics. These values will tell you if the $R^2$ is significantly different from 0.

The F-statistic can be obtained from the $R^2$ as: $F = \frac{ R^2 }{ 1- R^2} \times \frac{ \text{n-(k+1)} }{ \text{k}}$ where $n$ is your number of observations (10 in the sample data) and $k$ the number of variables in our model. We can verify that $F = \frac{ 0.5515 }{ 1- 0.5515} \times \frac{ \text{10-(4+1)} }{ \text{4}} = 1.537$. This F-statistic is then compared to a [distribution](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/f-statistic-value-test/) which is different for each number of degrees of freedom ($n-(k+1)$, and $k$), and for the desired alpha value for significance. Given the F-distribution, the F-statistic will be compared to a "threshold" F-value. If *F-statistic > F-threshold value* at significance level alpha, then *p-value < alpha*, meaning that the combination of all of your predictor variables explain the variance of $Rank$ at our alpha threshold (or lower).

Next, you can look at the regression coefficients, which will tell you by how many units $Rank$ increases or decreases for one unit of each predictor variable. The t-values (which is conceptually similar to the F-value) and p-values associated to each coefficient will tell you if the semi-partial correlation between $Rank$ and a given predictor is significant when the variance of every other predictor is regressed out of the variance of that given predictor. For example, the t- and p-values associated to the regression coefficient of $Inversions$ will tell you if there is a relation between $Rank$ and $Inversions$ for constant values of $Length$, $Height$, and $Speed$.

Finally, you can easily predict $Rank$ values by providing new roller coaster characteristics values with:

```
model <- lm(Rank ~ Lenght+Height+Speed+Inversions, data=RankForR)
predict(model, newdata=new_characteristics_values))
```